Move Klaviyo email Optin checkbox in Woocommerce checkout and set to pre checked?
Wondering if its possible to move the Klaviyo optin checkbox to right under the email address input, and have it preselected? via php snippet?
site is solidoralcare.co.nz


Does the solution provided below work for your question?

According to website link, provided in question post, to put Klaviyo optin checkbox right under the "email address" input field on woocommerce checkout page, the following code can be used.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields', 99 );
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['kl_newsletter_checkbox']['priority'] = 2;
    return $fields;
}

The value of "priority" in this code should be between value of priority of "email address" input field and input field next to "email address" input field. As checked on checkout page on website, at link, provided in question post, the priority of "email address" input field is 1, the priority of input field next to "email address" input field, that is, "first name" input field, is 10. So, to put Klaviyo optin checkbox right under the "email address" input field, the priority of "klaviyo newsletter checkbox" input field is set to 2 in above code. To get this checkbox field already selected, the following code can be used.
add_action( 'wp_footer' ,'custom_default_checked' );
function custom_default_checked() {
    echo '<script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             if( jQuery("#kl_newsletter_checkbox").length > 0 ) {                   
                  jQuery("#kl_newsletter_checkbox").attr("checked","checked");
             }
         });
         </script>';
}

Please note that all this code should be put in theme functions.php file.
